# Automatically split a sound file into multiple pieces with Logic

Tags: macos, audio, logic-pro

I'm wondering if Apple's Logic allows you to automatically split a sound file into multiple pieces based on criteria such as time-lapse (split a larger file into n 2 seconds chunks).

I'd rather not pay $499 to find out that it doesn't or doesn't do it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual is free

http://www.apple.com/logicstudio/resources/

And bear in mind that a great deal of any audio suite's functionality comes in the form of plugins from other vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Why spend $500 at all? You can get Audacity, an open source audio editor that's scriptable to do exactly that kind of thing?

See here: http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Automation

Comment: I have tried Audacity, and wasn't aware of the scripting.  I have to say though that the UI is pretty crappy, and given that it looks like it was designed to work on multiple platforms, I worry that the audio engine also tries to be HW neutral and doesn't take advantage of the native audio frameworks.

Comment: Understood. I was just trying to save you $500.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Marquee tool in Logic, you can select a precise sound file piece but I don’t think there is any automatic function to do many chunks at once, just one chunk at a time.
Edit; Yes, there IS a way to divide the selection into equal chunks.
There is a built-in Key Command to do it with. You just have to define which available Keys you wish to do it with.
Apple has a good Logic Pro forum, ask over there too.
Logic Pro X is only $199 now and well worth it.